# Changing values of elements in an array based on first encounter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of arrays that look like the following:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I want to change this array so that the first time it encounters a 1 in a position at an inner array, the remaining downward inner arrays get changed to a 1 at this position:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: What type is this array?  is it a list, a `bytearray`, `array.array`, etc?  What is printed when you do `print(repr(my_array))`?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to python so not entirely sure. The following is printed:array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])

Comment: Do you mean for each of the remaining elements, the item at the same position as the prior encountered 1 become 1 from that instance onwards?

Comment: @ZPython ok that comment makes it seem like an array of arrays. I think the question should be updated to reflect that

Comment: @vapurrmaid yes, that is exactly what I need.

Comment: downwards? or to the right? seems you want it downwards. So if the third inner array has a 1 on the 1st element, ALL 1st elements from then should be 1?

Comment: @PatrickArtner  yes I need it to be downwards. Or I can transpose the array and do it to the right if it makes it easier.

Comment: @ZPython Numpy arrays?

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes Numpy arrays. Again, sorry for not being specific as I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a numpy array to me.

**Option 1**
You can leverage [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.cumsum.html) to come up with an efficient solution.

```
>>> (x.cumsum(axis=0) > 0).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Where `x` is your input.

---

**Option 2**
[`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) [by @DSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244794/changing-values-of-elements-in-an-array-based-on-first-encounter/48244922#comment83472468_48244922) -

```
>>> np.maximum.accumulate(x)
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

If your arrays can contain values larger than `1`, add a `clip` call at the end.

```
np.maximum.accumulate(x).clip(None, 1)
```

Comment: I'm too lazy to write it up, but: np.maximum.accumulate(a)

Comment: Hmm, added a `clip` call at the end to snap max values to 1.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

As lists you could do:

```
data= [[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]]

d = {}    # store the index if they get 1 the first time
for r in data:
    for idx in range(len(r)):
        if (r[idx] == 1):
            d[idx] = 1        # this ones going to be 1 all the time now

        r[idx] = r[idx] or d.get(idx,0)  # leverages 0 == False and get  with 0 default

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use vector array and find the first occurrence in the array
or 
can use the loop which will take time O(n)

```
for(i=0;i < n;i++)

    if(a[i]==1)
      {
        c1++;
        break;
      }

for(j=I; j < n;j++)
    a[i]=1;
```

Comment: Doesn't look much like python

Comment: What is `c1`?  What is `I`?  What is `n`?